# Jenkins SMTP connection refused. What am I missing?

Tags: email, jenkins, smtp

I've got Jenkins ver 1.524 installed on a Windows 7 box and I'm trying to configure email but the "Test configuration" is reporting errors.  Jenkins is running as a service under my own domain account.

My settings are as follows:

```
SMTP server: smtp.corpdomain.com
Default user email suffix: @corpdomain.com
Not using authentication
Not using SSL
SMTP port: 25
Reply-To Address: tools@corpdomain.com
Charset: UTF-8
```

When I test the configuration, I usually get the following exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.amazon.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Yet every once in a while I receive the following instead:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 5.1.8 <nobody@nowhere>... Domain of sender address nobody@nowhere does not exist
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 553 5.1.8 <nobody@nowhere>... Domain of sender address nobody@nowhere does not exist
```

However, I am able to send mail from the command line without errors via both python script and java (using javax.mail) without authentication, and I'm able to telnet to the SMTP server on port 25, so I don't see how it could be a firewall issue.

One other note that may be related:  When I try to install a plug-in via the Jenkins web interface, I receive a 403 response for the URL "http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json?uctest".  However, I'm able to connect to that URL from a browser on the same machine.

Could this be a Tomcat configuration issue?  I'm not familiar with Tomcat so I'm not sure where to even start looking.  Maybe a Jenkins configuration that I've missed?  Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you accept the right response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still looks to me like your firewall is blocking Jenkins' service from accessing those ports -
especially as the connection times-out, which is typical for such cases.

Suggest you try to disable the firewall completely and see if there is any change.

Cheers

Answer (score 20):

FWIW The nobody@nowhere address is the default address Jenkins comes with for the system admin email address (which is used as the from address when sending emails)

you can change it at

Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Jenkins Location

Comment: That is what solved the problem for me. Jenkins Location needs to be defined in order for the test connection to work (looks like a bug).

Answer (score 5):

first, use port 465

second, get your email verified in AWS SES, and change your default sending email from here:
Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> System Admin e-mail address

Answer (score 1):

To check for conectivity problems from Jenkins, I would go to the **Script Console** at *Manage Jenkins* -> *Script Console*, and there, try to connect to the port you want to test (25 in your case), with a **Groovy** script like:

```
s = new Socket()
s.setSoTimeout(200)
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("smtp.corpdomain.com", 25), 200)
s.close()
```

If you don't receive any kind of `IOError`, then there is no problem with the conectivity.

**Note**: I could have used simply `new Socket("smtp.corpdomain.com", 25)` but it will try forever to connect if the Firewall ignores your attempts.

For the `SMTPSendFailedException` you eventually receive, as @paul-henry mention:

> The nobody@nowhere address is the default address Jenkins comes with for the system admin email address (which is used as the from address when sending emails)
>   you can change it at
>   Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Jenkins Location

Resources:

- [Networking with Groovy](http://programmingitch.blogspot.ca/2010/04/groovy-sockets-example.html)
- [Add a timeout when creating a new Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525972/add-a-timeout-when-creating-a-new-socket)

Answer (score -1):

*Thanks for submitting an edit. It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members
first, use port 465 second, get your email verified in AWS SES, and change your default sending email from here: Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> System Admin e-mail address*

Thanks. It helps me!

My problem was "550-Verification failed for "